# Apache Felix File Install is not working

Tags: java, apache-felix

I have downloaded `org.apache.felix.main.distribution-4.2.1`. It is working.

Now i want to use `org.apache.felix.fileinstall-3.2.6.jar`. I have downloaded it and put the jar File (File Install) into the Bundle Folder of Felix.

When I start Felix, File Install is automatically loaded. Very Fine. I start it like this:

`java -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=./deploy -jar bin/felix.jar`

First I created the `/deploy` Folder in the Main Folder of Felix. 
When I copy a Bundle.jar in the `/deploy` Folder, nothing happened.
I found many instructions on the Internet, but nothing is working.
I use a MAC.

Hope someone can help me.

Greetings

P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

File install will write a warning to the OSGi LogService when you tell it to monitor a directory that does not exist. I would advise you to install an implementation of the log service (for example from the Apache Felix project) and use the shell to view any log messages. They should tell you what's going on here.